# Deleting a list first vs. just reassigning it

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

When I have a list I need to clear, I usually just reassign it to a new empty list but is that the correct way or should I 'del' it first

example:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
mylist = []
```

or

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
del mylist
mylist = []
```

Regards

Comment: You cannot delete objects in Python. `del some_var` removes the name `some_var` from the namespace. The two pieces of code you've shown do the exact same thing, neither of which is to "clear a list".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: the first one is good, no need to `del` first.

Both examples end up in the same exact situation: there's the original list object, which has 0 references to it, and there's a new list object which is bound to the name mylist.